# Method gsub does not work as expected

Tags: ruby, gsub

I want to change `"@"` to `"\40"` in a string. But am not able to do so.

```
a = "srikanth@in.com"
a.gsub("@", "\40")
# => "srikanth in.com"
```

It's changing `\40` with space. Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: You're basically telling the program to: change the `"@"` to `"0x040"`, so you essentially have two "characters": one that repesents "4" in binary, and an ASCII zero. You probably want `"\x40"` (that's still just `@` though), maybe you actually want `"\\x40"` then you get `"email\x40example.com"` as a literal. If you literally want to replace it with `\40` then you need to use single quotes, as they don't interpolate: `'\40'`

Comment: Even with single quotes, it does not work.

Comment: @oldergod Oh, yes. It didn't work. I assumed it would without testing it.

Comment: Are you trying to url-encode the email address? This could be done with `require 'cgi'; CGI.escape("srikanth@in.com")`

Comment: @destielstarship, `"\40"` isn't the same as `"0x040"`. "\40" is using octal, and is the same as `" "`: `"\40".ord # => 32` and 32 is that ordinal value for a space. `"srikanth@in.com".gsub('@', "\40")
# => "srikanth in.com"`

Comment: @theTinMan At first I didn't realise what you were talking about until I saw my comment; I totally *effed* that up (I know they're not the same! Dooouh! Not to self: read before submitting). Also, I was assuming that he wanted to re-produce the "@" again as `"\\x40"` for whatever reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An other solution

```
puts a.gsub("@") {"\\40"}
# => srikanth\40in.com
```

Comment: Its giving the output as "srikanth\\40in.com".. Thats fine!

Answer (score 4):

backslashes have a special meaning in the second parameter of `gsub`. They refer to a possibly matched regex groups. I tried escaping, but couldn't get it to work. It works this way, though:

```
s = "srikanth@in.com"
s['@'] = '\\40'
s # => "srikanth\\40in.com"
```

Comment: @oldergod: doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: +1 This is one of the things I really like about Ruby, that we have such expressive ways to munge strings.

Answer (score 4):

`\\40` doesn't work because it refers to a capture group. From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

> If *replacement* is a `String` it will be substituted for the matched
>   text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups
>   of the form `\\d`, where *d* is a group number ...

You can use `gsub`'s hash syntax instead:

> If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.

Example:

```
a.gsub('@', '@' => '\\40')
#=> "srikanth\\40in.com"
```